# NSDateFormatter gives back totally wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

[image]

```
if (component != kDayComponent)
    {
        NSInteger i_d = [_datePicker selectedRowInComponent:kDayComponent],
        i_m = [_datePicker selectedRowInComponent:kMonthComponent],
        i_y = [_datePicker selectedRowInComponent:kYearComponent];

        NSString *d = _days[i_d];
//        NSString *m = [_months[i_m] length] == 1 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@", _months[i_m]] : _months[i_m];
        NSString *m = i_m+1 < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", i_m+1] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i_m+1];
        NSInteger y = [_years[i_y] integerValue];
        NSString *completeDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%ld", d, m, (long)y];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/YYYY"];

        NSDate *refreshDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:completeDate];

//        NSDate *refreshDate = [self dateFromMonth:m.integerValue+1
//                                          andYear:y
//                                           andDay:d.integerValue+1];
        NSLog(@"refreshDate: %@", refreshDate.description);

        [self refreshDaysFromDate:refreshDate];
    }
```

As you can see, `completeDate` has the correct string date value, I'm trying to format it with `NSDateFormatter` and hold the value in `refreshDate`.
The problem is `refreshDate` gives back totally wrong value, even when I did set up a `NSTimeZone` or `NSCalendar`.

Comment: Consult the excellent documentation : http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify the date formatter **YYYY** to **yyyy** you can get exact values

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

**yyyy** specifies the calendar year whereas **YYYY** specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar.
In most cases, **yyyy** and **YYYY** yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year

Comment: Also, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: You forgot to point out the importance of "dd" as well.  "DD" means day-of-year, not day-of-month.

Comment: It works, in run time I see the result is ok, but it still print the description still wrong.

Comment: dd is the day of the month, and DD is the day of the year.

Comment: @Chandukumar.Alasyam, Please again read the comment of "HotLicks".

Comment: yes @HotLicks "DD" means day-of-year, not day-of-month.but i forgot post in Answer .thanq

Answer (score 1):

modify the date formatter only

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```

this is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need "yyyy" not "YYYY" and "dd" not "DD".

y = year
Y = year of "Week of Year"

also (thks Hot Licks):
d = day in month
D = day of year

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)